# mount cephfs did't work after reboot

Tags: mount, cluster, ceph

I added this line:

```
10.10.10.10:6789:/     /mnt/ceph    ceph    name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/secret.key,noatime    0       2
```

to /etc/fstab in all of my nodes and executed "mount -a" and works good but in next system reboot it doesn't mount automatically and I have to execute "mount -a" after each reboot (I add "/bin/mount -a" in all rc.local files in all of my node) but I want the better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work well:

```
10.10.10.10:6789:/     /mnt/ceph    ceph    name=admin,secretfile=/etc/ceph/secret.key,noatime,_netdev    0       2
```

but in my situation with Ubuntu 12.04 and kernel v3.2, _netdev doesn't work and I had to add a script at /etc/network/if-up.d/fstab that contain this code:

```
#!bin/sh
mount -a
```